# Do not enumerate and count a page

Tags: chapters, page-numbering, count

I want to put a clean page before a new chapter. I can do this with:

```
\newpage

$\ $

\thispagestyle{empty}
```

The problem is the page is counting and I don't want this. I want to finish the chapter with a "number", put a white page and later push the begin of the new chapter with a "number"+1.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you using a `two-side`d document?

Comment: Have you tried adding `\addtocounter{page}{-1}` after `$\ $`?

Comment: Welcome. Are you trying to confuse your readers or do you simply consider them collateral damage? Odd numbered pages belong on the right; even numbered pages belong on the left. Anything else is simply confusing. A mixture of odd and even on left and right and every which-way is confusion on stilts.

Comment: Add a blank page before the chapters start after printing. Much less effort. Much easier to implement.

Comment: @Mico thank you your answer was usefull for me. That is the solution for my problem